# getElementsByTagName specific links only

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname

I'm trying to use Anarchy Media Player on my site but had to change code a bit because my media files/urls are not in standard format. It pulls the video files now but javascript is finding ALL links and tries to add player to it. I even added id "video" to video link but still finds all links on the page and adds player to it.
How can I separate those links to get player added to them only?

Here is the part of the javascript that looks for the links:

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0, o; o = all[i]; i++) {
    if(o.idName="video" && o.className!="amplink") {
        // Add player code...
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: why not [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName)?

Comment: @ajax333221 Because IE... Although using jQuery wouldn't be a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you're not just doing this:

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0, len = all.length; i<len; i++) {
    if(all[i].idName=="video" && all[i].className!="amplink") {
        // Add player code...
    }
}
```

That should work for you. Note that I stored the value of the array length so you don't have to look it up every iteration. Minimal, but does increase performance **slightly**.

You were also setting `idName` to video when you did `idName="video"` in your if statement, not comparing (that will always return true, which was your problem). Use the double equals operator (==) or the triple equals operator (===) to compare values.

Comment: @ Elliot,That did not seem to work but I did ended up wrapping link in div id=video and using *var all = document.getElementById ( "video" ).getElementsByTagName ( "a" );* Thank you tho. Now I'm facing different issue, need to recognize type of media to trigger only required player. I probably need to start new thread.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'd recommend doing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't mean `if (o.className == "amplink")`?

Besides that what you have is fine (except for the `o.idName="video"` bit which always returns true): http://jsfiddle.net/VpMVe/

Answer (score 0):

you can get elements using [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll), but it's [not supported in older browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=queryselector) (that would be older then IE8, FF3.5, Opera 10, Chrome 4 and Safari 3.1). It's similar to targetting elements using CSS selectors (and jQuery). here's [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d7VVF/1/) getting all links with class `video` to turn red.

```
function get(selector) {
    return document.querySelectorAll(selector)
}

(function() {
    //get all <a> with class "video"
    var video = get('a.video');

    //for each, turn them red
    for (var i = 0; i < video.length; i++) {
        video[i].style.color = 'red';

        //in your case, do whatever you want for each target here

    }
}())​
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no idName attribute. It's just `o.id`. And there can only be one id, so that's likely to cause some issues. Also you're assigning it, rather than comparing for equality which always evaluates to true. If you have more than one class, e.g. `class="amplink someOtherClass"` != amplink will evaluate to true. Better to do a match on the className. Like this:`&& !o.className.match(/ampLink/)`

Make a video on another class and do matches instead.